# Regular expression which finds "(double quote)

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I have a code editor and i want to implement the feature that if i press ctrl + shift + enter, then i get (" +\r""). (Like in eclipse).
To do that, i need to count the number of double quotes before the cursor. If the count is uneven, then the last double quote before the cursor is open and then i need to do the feature. But in that count i need to ignore \" which are enclosed in doubleqoutes (when defining a string), for instance:

```
var alpha:String = "Some \"text\"";
```

The correct count is 2

```
bar beta\":String = "Some \"text\"";
```

The correct count is 3

I cant even hope to figure out the correct regular expression for this, so please help.

Answer (score 0):

(?< !\\)\"  is probably what you want.  (?< !   )  signifies a negative lookbehind, that means only count what is past the stuff in the parens if what is after the ! does not exist.

There should be no space between < and !, seems like if I try to post it with no space, stackexchange doesn't like it.

Comment: I put your expression in [link](http://www.regexr.com/), and it says that lookbehind is not supported in javascript, i actually want to use it in actionscript, so do you think if that will make any problems?

Comment: I am not familliar with actionscript, so I don't know.  Another option would be to do this. (?:[^\\]|^)"  The (?: signifies a non capture group.  so it will only catch the " if it precedes any character other than \ or is the start of the string hence the (^).  The [^ means any character not in the []

Comment: bu i need to ignore \" only if it is between 2 ", in my example i check the whole line, i check `var alpha:String = "Some \"text\"";`, and not just `"Some \"text\""`